# Why use nullable Primary Key in Micronaut Data JDBC when working working with Kotlin data classes?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

in the actual documentation (https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#kotlinData) it says that generated attributes should be nullable. Why should I not pass for example Long.MAX_VALUE as the default and work with non-nullable types?

Comment: "Why should I not pass for example Long.MAX_VALUE as the default and work with non-nullable types?" - Having a default value for a primary key is an unusual and problematic thing to do.

Comment: It would be good to edit the question to ask 1 of the 2 questions that you posed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question. Can you refer to resources or provide some details on why this is problematic and post it as an answer?